# Reading TGA specification

Tags: specifications

I was reading through the TGA specification found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA, and I found this odd thing, I will say that its not only TGA spec I've seen this peculiar thing Microsoft and I assume pretty much everyone else is doing the same (of course not specifically for my quote but the general idea).

```
Color map type (field 2)
has the value:
0 if image file contains no color map
1 if present
**2-127 reserved by Truevision**
128-255 available for developer use
```

I marked the line I wondered about, why would Truvision reserve 2-127, what could be the outcome of this reservation.

I hope somebody could direct me in a direction or explain the general idea why a company would reserve space (<-- this could be the answer but I think there is more to it)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most protocols or file specifications set aside a reserved space for "future expansion."  In this example, Truevision could extend the TGA spec to include a different way of representing the colormap while keeping the same file structure.